# Error could not find or load main class

Tags: java, junit, terminal, classpath

I want to run my class in terminal window:

```
D:\workEclipse2\JUnitTest\bin>java -classpath D:\JUnit\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;D:\
JUnit\junit-4.12.jar tax.TaxCommandLineRunner
```

Code of my TaxCommandLineRunner class:

```
package tax;

import java.util.List;

import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

public class TaxCommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JUnitCore core = new JUnitCore();

        Result result = core.run(AllTests.class);

        if(result.wasSuccessful()){
            System.out.println("All tax tests was successfull");
        }else{
            System.out.println("These tax tests was failure");

            List<Failure> fails = result.getFailures();
            fails.forEach(failure -> System.out.println(failure.getMessage()));
        }


    }

}
```

Compiled `AllTests.class` and `TaxCommandLineRunner.class` are located in `D:\workEclipse2\JUnitTest\bin`.

My jars file are located in `D:\JUnit`

I can't find what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I input in terminal window:

```
  D:\workEclipse2\JUnitTest\bin>java -classpath D:\JUnit\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;D:\JUnit\junit-4.12.jar;. tax.TaxCommandLineRunner
```

I assume that point after semicolon means classpath of Windows, that is in first case I don't include my standart java\jre.

Comment: Same issue. Adding the dot after the last semicolon fixed my isses!

Answer (score 0):

You must also add the actual directory to your classpath:

```
D:\workEclipse2\JUnitTest\bin>java -classpath .;D:\JUnit\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;D:\
JUnit\junit-4.12.jar tax.TaxCommandLineRunner
```